# USB interconnection between computer and iPhone failing due to “link not ready” error

Tags: internet-connection, wired-networking

I am trying to connect to the internet on my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad running Ubuntu 18.04) by connecting to my phone (iPhone 6s) though a USB-Lightning cord.

This has worked for months but suddenly failed, possibly due to a software/firmware upgrade. Here is the what seems to be the relevant part of the log:

```
[  +0.012080] ipheth 1-3:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
[  +0.000012] usbcore: registered new interface driver ipheth
[  +0.009028] ipheth 1-3:4.2 enp0s20f0u3c4i2: renamed from eth0
[  +0.050073] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  +0.000002] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  +0.000005] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  +0.319300] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3c4i2: link is not ready
[  +0.000606] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3c4i2: link is not ready
[  +0.003802] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  +0.186225] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  +0.002091] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s20f3: link is not ready
[  +0.193558] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
[  +0.000488] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s20f3: link is not ready
[  +0.087906] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s20f3: link is not ready
[  +6.065263] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[  +2.736662] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  +0.000011] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  +0.000009] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  +1.081306] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[  +0.000002] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6032
[  +0.000000] thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[  +0.614643] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
[  +0.000011] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1001 -> 0x1)
[  +0.000017] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
[  +0.000008] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0x1 -> 0x0)
[  +0.000008] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: control channel stopped
[ +10.943627] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[  +0.000001] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6032
[  +0.000001] thinkpad_acpi: please report the conditions when this event happened to ibm-acpi-devel@lists.sourceforge.net
[Dec10 08:14] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ +11.118975] thinkpad_acpi: unknown possible thermal alarm or keyboard event received
[  +0.000004] thinkpad_acpi: unhandled HKEY event 0x6032
```

Presumably, the "link is not ready" is where things fail? I am wondering if this is a firmware/driver issue and maybe reverting an upgrade would fix things? I am going to see if I can figure out how to do that. I am able to connect using the phone as a wireless hot spot but not using Bluetooth.

Here are the items that have most recently been upgraded:

```
intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20191115.1ubuntu0.18.04.1, 3.20191115.1ubuntu0.18.04.2)
grub-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
grub2-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
grub-pc:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 (1.93.14+2.02-2ubuntu8.13, 1.93.15+2.02-2ubuntu8.14)
unattended-upgrades:amd64 (1.1ubuntu1.18.04.12, 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.13)
libnss3:amd64 (2:3.35-2ubuntu2.5, 2:3.35-2ubuntu2.6)
linux-firmware:amd64 (1.173.12, 1.173.13)
```

Comment: Odd. Since there was a firmware update, did you try rebooting your machine?

Comment: Yes, several times

Comment: This writeup confuses me because iPhones don't support Thunderbolt, and don't have a USB connector. So the cable is probably a USB Type-C to Lightning cable (which is just a specialized USB cable, not a Thunderbolt-compatible cable at all). But then whatever log that is (which log *is* it?) does say something about Thunderbolt, which shouldn't be involved here. Very confusing.

Comment: The log is from dmesg -H. I thought that Thunderbolt was the name of the shape that you need for the iPhone charger port but could well be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that redoing the installation with `apt install --reinstall <list-of-packages>` fixed this problem. Presumably this means that the installation was somehow corrupted, although I'm still not sure how this was not flagged somehow or how I could have figured that out from the error messages I was getting. But in any case the problem is fixed now.